# Print to thermal printer from Open office Calc

Tags: printing, openoffice.org

I'd like to print receipts to an epson TM-T88IV from open office calc (Spreadsheet).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The following is a link to a list of Printers that are known to work with Ubuntu. Just because it is not listed though does not mean it won't work.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsPrinters

A quick google search for your printer type and ubuntu made it apparent that your printer will indeed work with Ubuntu.